# I'm Changing the behaviour of a javaFX component by adding a do-nothing listener

Tags: java, events, data-binding, properties, javafx

I've been playing around with JavaFX and have been pretty happy --for the most part.

One of the things I'm wondering is if there is supposed to be any difference in behavior between a property with no listeners on it and a property with a do-nothing invalidation listener on it.

I'm thinking there might be some subtlety in the lazy-ness of javaFX properties and bindings that I'm missing. I've got a very evident bug that exists when I comment out the code in the empty_bug_fixing_listener block.

```
    Data<String, Number> linkerPoint = new Data<>();

    linkerPoint.setXValue(SeriesLinkerAxisName);

    ObservableValue<Number> rightNeighbourBinding =
            hostElement.getRightNeighbour().axisMagnitude;

    empty_bug_fixing_listener: {
        rightNeighbourBinding.addListener((source, oldV, newV) -> {});
    }

    linkerPoint.YValueProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
            () -> projectThroughMyAxisIntoVisibleRightNeighbour(expensivePoint),
            hostElement.axisMagnitude,
            rightNeighbourBinding,
            hostElement.sourceElements
    ));
    return linkerPoint;
```

looking under the debugger, I've noticed that 2 pieces of state change when I use the addListener method. One is the `valid` boolean field on the property that seems to be used to track changes that nobody sees. Its set to `true` by a call to `getValue()`, which doesn't fix my bug if made manually.

It also creates an undocumented semi-recursive `helper` object that I don't understand. It seems to be some kind of event sourcing scheme, and I don't quite understand its implementation.

A little bit more at the macro level:

I'm trying to create a parallel coordinates plot (PCP) using a collection of XYCharts in JavaFX. I've been largely successful, except for the above mentioned issue. Because the PCP uses adjacent XY charts, each individual XY chart has to find its adjacent charts value, and plot that value in its own scale, leading to some uncomfortable math. Furthermore, the scales of each of the axis is changing and the neighbours themselves are re-orderable. The LinkerPoint is one XYCharts point for its neighbours axis projected into its own axis, so that it can be rendered as a contiguous line.

So we get expected (with empty change listener):
[image]

Actual (without empty change listener):
[image]

Any help much appreciated. As I mention in the comments below I will try to reduce this problem down to some unit tests, but I'm really not sure how to approach reducing it, since its enamored with complex (at least to non-haskell programmers) binding logic.

Comment: What is your very evident bug?  What is your question?

Comment: should adding an empty listener to a property changes its behaviour?

Comment: I don't understand and you don't describe what the behaviour change is.  Can you edit your question to be more explicit in your description and perhaps provide an (executable) [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that somebody could copy and paste and run it to reproduce the issue you are seeing?

Comment: My question is what should the behaviour change be? I'll start working on an mcve, but it will take me some time since I really don't know whats relevant and not relevant to this suprising-behaviour and/or bug. I'll add some more images above and I'll elaborate a little on the description.

Comment: You are attaching a "do-nothing _change_ listener", not _invalidation_ listener. A change listener causes 1) the value of a binding to be evaluated eagerly on every invalidation; and 2) the binding be marked as _valid_. So the problem almost certainly stems from the fact that without adding this empty listener, your binding is not _invalidated_ and _re-validated_ often enough. Why? My bet is that your `projectThroughMyAxisIntoVisibleRightNeighbour` method does not cause `rightNeighbourBinding` be marked as valid, i.e. does not actually use its value.

Comment: In other words, recomputing a binding (i.e. the lambda you pass to `createDoubleBinding`) should cause all its dependencies become _valid_.